# Getting data from textfield and determining if yes or cancel was pressed

Tags: javascript, input, message

I am currently working on on some JavaScript examples from w3schools and I was wondering if there was a way to get the text info entered by the user and at the same time determine if the user clicks OK or cancel.

I know to determine if OK or cancel was pressed by:

```
var r=confirm("Press a button");
 if (r==true)
   {
   alert("You pressed OK!");
   }
 else
   {
   alert("You pressed Cancel!");
   }
```

And to get the data from a text field :

```
var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
  document.write("<p>Hello " + name + "! How are you today?</p>");
  }
```

But is there a way to get both of these at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p;
p = prompt('What is your age ?','');

if (p == null) {
    alert('Cancel was clicked.');
}
else {
    alert('OK was clicked.');
}
```

If the user clicks cancel or presses the X then `p` is null

Comment: @user1219627: but `p` will be `NULL` if they clicked cancel. If they just entered a blank name, `p` will not be `NULL`, but will be blank. So this solution should do what you are asking for. AFAIK, you can't get the text that was in the box if the user clicked cancel, because it isn't assigned to anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (name == null)
    alert("CANCEL");
else if (name == "")
    alert("OK BUT BLANK");
else
    alert("YOU ENTERED "+ name);
```

Comment: ...or are you asking if you can capture the cancel button press on a prompt?

Comment: This just adds a message box before entering the second prompt. I want to know on the enter your name part if they press cancel or OK

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes I exactly both text and button choice on one prompt

Comment: @Travesty3 I want to capture the ok/cancel and the text entry from the same prompt

Comment: Sorry, looks like @Computer beat me to the correct answer, but I'll modify mine anyways.

Comment: @Travesty3 Thanks! If i could give you both the correct answer I would but I'll still +1 u